# Spring security is giving 403 inspite of right credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am getting access denied from spring . Can somebody please help me with this

---

I am using spring 4.3

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping (value = "/api/secured/resource/school")
@Secured ({ ApplicationConstants.Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN, ApplicationConstants.Role.SCHOOL_ADMIN })
public class SchoolController
{

    @Autowired
    private SchoolService schoolService;

    @PostMapping (consumes = "application/json")
    @Secured ({ ApplicationConstants.Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN })
    public @ResponseBody ResponsePayload createSchool (HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody School school)
            throws ServiceException
{
}

 interface Role
    {

        String SYSTEM_ADMIN = "SYSTEM_ADMIN";

        String SCHOOL_ADMIN = "SCHOOL_ADMIN";
    }
```

As in the log below you can see that the user has two Authorities

SYSTEM_USER, SYSTEM_ADMIN still its giving me Access Denied

Spring configuration

```
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
        <form-login login-page="/loginPage"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/loginPage" />
        <custom-filter ref="loginFilter" after="FIRST" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>
```

2016-07-15 16:03:12,525 DEBUG MethodSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7670236f: Principal: SystemUser [userId=1, name=Administrator, email=admin@tepachi.com, mobilePhone=9999999999, status=ACTIVE]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 1h5x6yxtd1m0y1ogs4h5vfo1yl; **Granted Authorities: SYSTEM_USER, SYSTEM_ADMIN**
2016-07-15 16:03:12,525 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@55951fcd, returned: 0
2016-07-15 16:03:12,527 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@46ab4efc, returned: 0
2016-07-15 16:03:12,529 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [public com.tepachi.web.response.ResponsePayload com.tepachi.web.controller.SchoolController.createSchool(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.tepachi.db.entities.user.School) throws com.tepachi.exception.ServiceException]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: **Access is denied**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was spring 4 onwards it prepends ROLE_ to the authority granted.

> **hasRole([role])** :
>   Returns true if the current principal has the specified role. By default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

More information can be found here [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-common-built-in)